# Render a webpage (includes some javascripts) in Python

Tags: javascript, python, html

I'm new in programming with Python. I just want to create a little webcrawler.
I already created my idea in C# but my Raspberry Pi doesn't support the Mono project in the right way (There is a long theard about a special problem, which is still not solved and this for about a year now). Because of this I need to code it in Python. I want a simple application which opens a website, waits some seconds till the JavaScript changes some stuff on the website (some simple links) then it needs to find a specific link by his id. When it finds the link, it needs to visit / click the link so that I can see the source code of the new website for other works later. Perhaps you guys could help me out with some links? I already searched by my self but I couldn't find anything what could help me directly.
Thank you all!

Comment: Have you heard of Selenium, Watir or Firefox's WebDriver? I'm sure there are libraries for Python to do just this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [Selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) with Python.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly that I need and it's easy to use!